# react native use of debounce doesnt work on android device

Tags: android, react-native, lodash, debouncing

The wrapper component below works fine for IOS but doesnt actually debounce when run on android.  i.e  if I pound the opacity it generates lots of calls

any clues?

I havent been able to find anything that says it shouldnt work on Android

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)

  this.onPressDebounced = _.debounce((...params) => this.onPressed(...params), 500, {
    'leading': true,
    'trailing': false
  })
}

onPressed(...params) {
  if (this.props.onPress) {
    this.props.onPress(...params)
  }
}

render() {
  return ( <TouchableHighlight { ...this.props } onPress = { this.onPressDebounced }> {this.props.children} </TouchableHighlight>
  )
}
```

Comment: If that is truely the seen behaviour it's probably best to raise an issue over in https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues

Comment: yep, looks like android is failing to see/act on the params.  default works.

Comment: Yea - the owner of lodash (https://stackoverflow.com/users/166625/john-david-dalton) is really chill and great with issues. If this is the seen behaviour, please raise an issue (and link back to here)

Answer (score 2):

I met this problem today. And I found a simple solution to avoid touch bounce.

So I check the variable `this.lockSubmit` before execute core service codes. Exit function if it is a falsy value, because it means there have another unfinished touch invoke.

The next statement is set `this.lockSubmit` to `true`.

And then I can execute async operation or navigate operation after `this.lockSubmit = true`

After service codes has been callback or finished. I set `this.lockSubmit` to `false`. this statement means a touch invoke is finished. But sometimes the service codes will finish quickly, so I add `setTimeout` to relase this lock variable delay.

```
class PageA extends React.Component {
    // also work well with async function
    onSubmit() {
        if(this.lockSubmit) return;
        this.lockSubmit = true;

        // validate form
        if(this.form.validate()) {
            // jump to another page
            this.props.navigation.push('Uploading');
        }

        this.setTimeout(() => this.lockSubmit = false, 500);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                <Text>Submit</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on what you did to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please try in this way it should work

```
onPressDebounced = debounce(
  () =>
   this.onPressed(),
  500,
);

render() { 
  return ( 
    <TouchableHighlight 
      { ...this.props } 
      onPress = { this.onPressDebounced}> 
      {this.props.children} 
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )
}
```

Comment: yeah, this works, but the behaviour isnt quite what I want.  (I want act on leading edge, not on trailing).  But its better than completely broken.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with android as well and couldn't find a way around it using lodash debouncing or throttling.

My current solution, which is working fine so far, is an encapsulation of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54035385/564479). It's a HOC that you can wrap around any component with an onPress prop.

```
import React from 'react';

const withPreventDoublePress = WrappedComponent => {
  const DISABLED_TIME = 1000;

  class PreventDoublePress extends React.PureComponent {
    originalOnPress = () => {
      this.props.onPress && this.props.onPress();
    };

    onPress = () => {
      if (this.onPressDisabled) return;
      this.onPressDisabled = true;

      this.originalOnPress();

      setTimeout(() => {
        this.onPressDisabled = false;
      }, DISABLED_TIME);
    };

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} onPress={this.onPress} />;
    }
  }

  PreventDoublePress.displayName = `withPreventDoublePress(${WrappedComponent.displayName ||
    WrappedComponent.name})`;
  return PreventDoublePress;
};

export default withPreventDoublePress;
```